# insert huge data via select statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am inserting the data into one table via select statement , But that select statement has huge data like 25milion , so its taking long time 5-6 hours and failing , So Can we insert the same data like batch wise ?

Kindly suggest.

I can not change the query, I need to insert entire data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for the table(s); the sample data you are trying to insert; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output.

Comment: [`dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_<>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.html#GUID-F93E6373-8ADA-4683-AD02-66CAB1FF5A96). Then run tasks

Answer (score 1):

Tuning is a huge subject, and requires a lot of data and knowledge of your environment, so we can only give guidelines here.

1. You must first determine where it is spending it's time. It could very well be in the `SELECT` portion, if you are doing any table joins. Use `v$active_session_history` data or some performance visualization tool that uses ASH to determine what plan step is taking the most amount of time, and diagnose and address the issue surgically by modified or hinting your query. This is a big topic and not something that can be explained further in this forum. You may need to ask your DBA for help with this.
2. If the time is all on the insert load step itself, check to see how many indexes there are. If there are a lot of indexes, you may want to disable them for the load, then rebuild them when the load is complete.
3. Make sure you are using parallelism (assuming you have enough CPUs and you've asked your DBA what degree of parallelism is appropriate for your system), and for the insert piece, that you have enabled parallel DML:

   ```
   alter session enable parallel dml;
   insert /*+ append parallel(8) */ into tbl SELECT ...
   ```
4. Make sure your process isn't actually being blocked and doing nothing. Again, `v$active_session_history` will tell you the predominate wait event and if it's a concurrency class wait (enqueue, pin, suspended due to tablespace full, etc..) then you'll need to resolve the blocking issue.

I'm sure there's a simple solution. I see `INSERT SELECT`s of 25 million rows all the time that take only a dozen seconds or so. That's really not a very large number in the Oracle world.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an indication of how to process something in batches in parallel: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.html